# On the idea of classifying functions in terms of types of equations that require these functions in order to be solved.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, soft-question

-Sets of numbers are often presented in terms if types of equations that require such numbers in order to be solved.

-For example, we need integers to solve (for $x$)  $ a+x = c$ when $c$ is less than $a$. And we need rationals to solve  (for $x$) $ax = b$ , when $\frac ba$ is not an integer. Etc.

-Hence the idea of doing the same thing for functions. I mean, the idea of presentng,  so to say, the genealogy of functions in terms of types of equations they allow to solve ( with an increasing degree of complexity).

-For example, we need " radical functions" ( and sometimes the absolute value function) to solve equations of the form : $x^n = a $.

We need logarithm  functions to solve exponential equations.

These are just examples.

I recently heard about a mysterious "Lambert" function allowing to solve equations such as $ 2^x=x$.

- My aim, in asking this question, is to know whether we could gain a systematic classification of functions by proceeding in this fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a system (sort of) exists. A function is *polynomial* if it is a polynomial in (one or several) variables; it is *rational* if it is given by the quotient of polynomials; it is *algebraic* if it can be expressed as the root of a polynomial (i.e., for example $y x^2 + y^3 + x = 0$ defines $y$ as a function of $x$, and viceversa); then there are *trascendental* functions that aren't algebraic. Of those, the functions $e^x$, $\ln x$, $\sin x$, $\cos x$, their rational combinations and their inverses are considered *elementary trascendentals* (you know them from calculus), *higher trascendental functions* are typically defined as integrals that aren't elementary (like $\operatorname{li}(x) = \int_0^x \frac{d t}{\ln t}$ or $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z - 1} e^x \, d x$ when $z$ is not an integer) or by non-elementary solutions to differential equations (look up e.g. the Bessel functions).

But all of those are (mostly) "well-behaved" functions (continuous, differentiable at most points). They are a tiny part of all the functions, which include strange beasts like [Weierstrass' function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) (continuous everwhere, nowhere differentiable), [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) (continuous at all irrational $x$, discontinuous at rational $x$), [Conway's base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) (everywhere discontinuous). Even a seemingly innocent equation like [Cauchy's functional equation](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf) $f(x) + f(y) = f(x + y)$ has bizarre solutions (no, the obvious $f(x) = c x$ for some $c$ isn't the only type of solution).

This leads to *very* deep depths... way over my head, to be sure. An understandable (to a relative layperson, i.e., college calculus covered) introduction to some of the subtleties you'll find in Dunham's "Calculus Gallery" (Princeton University Press, 2008).

Comment: Thanks for this fine answer!